# How do I programmatically find whether the intermediate certificate was served by the web server?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpwebrequest, x509

My C# code uses `HttpWebRequest` to send requests to a web service via HTTP over SSL (`https://` prefixed URLs). The service has it's coolservice.example.com certificate which is signed by certificate authority intermediate certificate which is in turn signed by the trusted root certificate authority certificate. The latter must be in the caller certificate store and marked as "trusted root", otherwise all that SSL trust chain thing makes no sense. However the intermediate certificate may come from either of the different sources:

- the web server may serve it together with its own certificate (as in "here's my certificate and btw it was signed with this certificate which was signed with something you likely trust, please just check the signatures along the trust chain")
- the caller may automagically retrieve the intermediate from the certificate authority (AIA protocol or something) - I know this because I've been interfacing with a web service which didn't have the intermediate certificate installed and "it just worked"
- the caller may have the intermediate certificate installed in their store

I need to check that the web server properly serves (not only has in the trust store but actually serves the certificate) the intermediate while the SSL handshake is in progress. [This test site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) even shows "sent by server" next to the intermediate. So I guess such check is possible.

How do I craft such a check with C# and .NET Framework?

So far I've only come across `HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` which accepts the web service certificate (`X509Certificate` object) and the trust chain (`X509Chain` object). The trust chain lists all the certificates in the chain however I cannot see anything detailing where the certificate was obtained.

How I programmatically find whether the intermediate certificate was server by the web server or it was obtained from elsewhere?

Comment: If you find yourself without answer - you can try playing with SSL trace (you can follow sample & links from here for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5985497/2170171); you'll probably will need to match some trace messages across .Net sources to see what they are doing. That helped me a lot when I was digging some SSL stuff in .Net stack.